# SWL Error Function has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using *ASP.NET 3.5* and *SQL Server 2008*.

I have a `SQLDataSource` & `Gridview`. I am trying to update 2 tables at the same time using a *stored procedure* in *SQL*.
`SQLDatasource` is passing 7 parameters.
5 parameters that the stored procedaure needs, Return value & StudentID.

Not sure if the error is in my `SQLDatasorce` or my *stored procedure*.

Here's my *ASPX* Code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsUserLoginNLevels" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizStarConnectionString %>"

 SelectCommand="SELECT UserLogins.StudentID, UserLogins.StudentName, UserLogins.UserID,
      UserLogins.Password, UserLevels.GrammarStart, UserLevels.GrammarCurrent,
      UserLevels.MathStart, UserLevels.MathCurrent 
      FROM UserLogins 
      INNER JOIN UserLevels ON UserLogins.StudentID = UserLevels.StudentID" 

  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [UserLogins] WHERE [StudentID] = @original_StudentID"

  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [UserLogins] ([StudentName], [UserID], [Password]) 
     VALUES (@StudentName, @UserID, @Password)" 

  UpdateCommand="UpdateUserLoginsAndUserLevels" 

UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_StudentID" />
    </DeleteParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="StudentName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GrammarStart" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MathStart" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="RETURN_VALUE" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>

    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="StudentName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My *Stored Procedure* is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserLoginsAndUserLevels] (  
@StudentName    VARCHAR(50), 
@UserID     NCHAR(10), 
@Password   NCHAR(10), 
@GrammarStart   NCHAR(10), 
@MathStart  NCHAR(10))

AS 
DECLARE @StudentID INT; 


BEGIN Transaction 
    BEGIN TRY         

        SELECT * From UserLogins                   
            Where StudentID = @StudentID 

        UPDATE UserLogins                  
            SET 
                StudentName= @StudentName,
                UserID = @UserID,
                Password = @Password
            Where StudentID = @StudentID  

        UPDATE UserLevels                  
            SET 
                GrammarStart= @GrammarStart,
                MathStart = @MathStart
                FROM UserLevels
                INNER JOIN UserLogins ON UserLogins.StudentID = UserLevels.StudentID 
            WHERE (UserLevels.StudentID =  @StudentID)
    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH         
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT         
        -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that          
        -- capture information for RAISERROR.         
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()         
        -- Rollback the failed transaction         
        ROLLBACK;         
        -- Raise an error: with the original error information.         
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, 1); 
    END CATCH 
COMMIT Transaction;
```

Have't figured how to post code yet. Sorry.

Comment: To post code indent it all by 4 spaces. (Select it and hit the `{}` icon to do this)

Comment: Is anything binding to this datasource?  Are you messing with the parameters at all in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not double adding parameters.  Since you are adding them in the aspx page you do not need to add them in your code behind.

For example if your code behind has this in it:

```
sqldsUserLoginNLevelsUserID.UpdateParameters.Add(new Parameter("UserID ", TypeCode.Int32));
```

It could explain your error.

If you need to set the value from code behind do it like this:

```
sqldsUserLoginNLevelsUserID.UpdateParameters["UserID "].DefaultValue = "1";
```

Comment: I changed my Stored Procedure to: <code> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserLoginsAndUserLevels] ( @StudentID INT, @StudentName VARCHAR(50), @UserID NCHAR(10), @Password NCHAR(10), @GrammarStart NCHAR(10), @MathStart NCHAR(10)) AS --DECLARE @StudentID INT; It's now working!